# FFMPEG get mono WAV audio 8khz 16 bit out of mp4 video

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to extract audio out of MP4 video file using FFMPEG. Just extracting audio is easy enough but I can't figure out the right parameters to get audio in mono 8khz 16 bit.

Basically I need to take all of the audio channels out of the video file and merge them into a mono 8khz 16 bit file. Is it possible to do so with FFMPEG?

I tried running

> ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 audio.wav

Bit it's not giving me the exact result I want.

Comment: Please define "all audio channels". Do they really need to be overlaid? Or do you just want to mix a stereo source into mono? What's your input video's audio channel layout? Please include the full, uncut command line output, otherwise we're just guessing.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `-ac 1` (See the [FFmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation), or the man page with `man ffmpeg`) to limit the output to one channel.

Then use `-ar 8000` for 8kHz and `-acodec pcm_s16le` for 16 bit.